# Sorting bibliography by Journaltitle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I use Biblatex. I'd like to sort my bibliography by journaltitle (and then by date, or by author): is there a package or a bibliography style that does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a pre-built solution, but you can easily define a custom sorting scheme with `\DeclareSortingTemplate`.

The example below sorts by `journaltitle`, `year`, `volume`, `name` and `title`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{jyvnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{journaltitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=jyvnt}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,glashow,weinberg,yoon,moore}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Moore, Gordon E. (1965). ‘Cramming more components onto integrated circuits’. In: Electronics 38.8, pp. 114–117. Aksın, Özge et al. (2006). ‘Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions’. In: J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13, pp. 3027–3036. Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. Glashow, Sheldon (1961). ‘Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions’. In: Nucl. Phys. 22, pp. 579–588. Yoon, Myeong S. et al. (2006). ‘Palladium pincer complexes with reduced bond angle strain: efficient catalysts for the Heck reaction’. In: Organometallics 25.10, pp. 2409–2411. Weinberg, Steven (1967). ‘A Model of Leptons’. In: Phys. Rev. Lett. 19, pp. 1264–1266.]